# Total harmonic distortion (THD) of a circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, harmonics

[image: Calculate the output THD of this circuit.]

Where \$V_{sin}\$ is sinusoidal with frequency \$f_{1} = 1 kHz\$.

The THD is defined as the sum of the power of all harmonics (except the fundamental) divided by the power of the fundamental harmonic.

I calculated \$V_{out}\$ wrt \$\omega\$ and the time-averaged power from there. Then I tried evaluating this power at frequencies \$f_{(n)} = n \cdot 1 kHz\$ and calculating the THD from this, but I can't make this sum.

This question was in a 3h exam, and it was worth 10%, so it should take around 18min to do. It can't be that complex numerically.

I'm most interested in the process of solving this over the actual answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The circuit is perfectly linear, i.e you have no non-linear effect going on in there, so there should be no THD. What's more, the source only outputs a single, fixed frequency signal. Did you mean attenuation for higher, or lower harmonics?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Wow you are absolutely right. So the THD = 1, then. I didn't realize capacitors were linear. Mainly it was its impedance that confused me (1/jwC): it varies with frequency, but doesn't "create" any new frequency. Thank you! Solved.

Comment: No, THD will be zero @AsierR.

Comment: You're right, THD = 0. @Andyaka

Comment: Some real-world capacitors are non-linear, that non-linearity being explained as electric-field forces cause a thickness variation in the dielectric.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit only uses **linear components**. Ideal resistors, capacitors, and inductors are linear components meaning, their behavior is independent of the amplitude of the voltage and current.

As such this circuit is **unable** to generate harmonics. For that there would need to be a non-linear component present. For example a diode or a transistor.

So the answer is: THD = 0

Obviously this is a question to test your knowledge of the relation between (non) linear circuits and distortion of signals.